# bad links mark pages in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, browser

I have a problem with links in firefox. only happens in firefox and in chrome works well.
If I have a board and I link a document like this:

```
<a href="file.html#mark"> link </a>
```

I have in the document:

```
<a name="mark"> </a>
```

Anyone know that in going from the front to the page does not take me to that part of the document? only works in firefox when already loaded page while chrome always work.

Comment: Use `id` `<a id="mark" href="#"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Use

`<a id="mark"> </a>`

instead.

Or you could link to a heading directly like:

`<h1 id="mark">This is my heading</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `id`  `<a id="mark" href="#"> </a>`

**Call** by

```
 <a href="file.html#mark"> link </a>

  (or)

 <a href="#mark"> link </a>  (if it is same page)
```

Comment: i have <a id="mark" href="file.html#mark">link</a> and file.html page <a name="mark" href="#"></a>

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-jQuery-object ..click this link ,directly show the jquery object..